# How to run a specific test plan

Tags: perl

I am setting up my test environment to run tests on file changes, but I don't want to run all the test plans when test cases are changed.

How can I run a specific test plan in Perl? For example, I only want to run "test2"?

t/test.t

```
use Test::More;  
ok(1, "test1");

ok(1, "test2");
... 
done_testing();
```

Comment: It seems impossible to provide a useful answer without knowing anything about the test framework or harness you're using.

Comment: You can comment and suggest me to modify my question, I don't see which part in the question makes you want to close it. Basically I am asking how to auto run a test case when sources are changed, why does this have any relationship with frameworks? I'll use the framework that provides this feature, just want to know how to do it.

Comment: If I recall, calling "`done_testing()`" when no tests have run doesn't work out so well, so you'll need at least an ok(1) to kick things off.  After that, there's no problem making some tests optional as a "simple matter of programming".  If you need external control of which tests get run, the common way to do it is to set environment variables.  Many module authors use RELEASE_TESTING or AUTHOR_TESTING for tests that don't need to run on end-users systems, for example.  Then within the test script, check the env variable, and branch logic to control which run.

Comment: Thanks, you're right about the `done_testing()`, the ENV approach doesn't work in this case, I am asking how to selectively run a test case inside a module, not which file to run, if that's the case, `Test::Class::Load` can do it.

Comment: `if ( $ENV{RELEASE_TESTING} ) { ok(1); } else { ok(2) }`

Comment: umm, gotcha, this might work, in other languages you can group test cases using tags, and you test only the specific tags http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing#testonly. I don't know if any existing perl modules provide similar functionality.

Comment: Yes, read Test::More's documentation; you can do something like the following: `subtest 'skippy' => sub {
    plan skip_all => 'cuz I said so' unless $ENV{TEST_THIS_TOO}
    pass('this test will never be run');
};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'd do the following:

1 - if you might want to separate some test from the others, put it in some other test suite...

```
t/00-always_runs.t
t/01-maybe_not_so_often.t
```

2 - if the test you're willing to skip depends on some feature or availability on some object, try using a skip block like in Test::More documentation

```
SKIP: {
    skip $why, $how_many unless $have_some_feature;

    ok( foo(),       $test_name );
    is( foo(42), 23, $test_name );
};
```

From [https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::More](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test%3a%3aMore)

Hope it helps and gets you going! Good luck.

Comment: Why do you put numbers in front of file names? I saw this many times.

Comment: @Sawyer Filenames usually appear sorted in directories.  The TAP harness also executes in sorted order.  Perhaps you want 01-.... to run first, and 02-.... second.  ...though this is less effective when running tests in parallel, at least it helps keep things tidy.

Comment: @Sawyer, exactly because what DavidO said :)